# The form action and anchor is not working in codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was trying to set the action of a form in the `form_open()`. And there I specified the login file (present in the controller and its also the base controller file), and its function named as `validate`. But the page is giving *404 object not found* error. What is it that I'm doing wrong? And the same error occurs in `anchor('login/signup','Create Account');`. I hope I'm able to explain myself.

/controller/login.php

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('HTML');
    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('login_form');

}

function signup()
{
    $this->load->view('signup_form');
}
function validate()
{
}

}
?>
```

/view/login_form.php

```
<div class="form_login">

<?php echo heading("Login",1); ?> 

<?php
echo form_open('login/validate');
echo form_input('username','','placeholder ="Enter Username"');
echo form_password('pass','','placeholder ="Enter Password"');
echo form_submit('sub','Submit');
echo br();
echo anchor('login/signup','Create Account');
echo form_close();
?> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create form also like that --

```
<div class="form_login">

<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/insert">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder ="Enter Username">
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder ="Enter Password">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></br>
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/signup">Create Account</a>
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: have you set base_url in config file ?

Comment: and i've set my login page to base controller

Comment: can i known what`s your skype id ?? by skype i can solve easily.and i can do also more help in codeigniter framework

Comment: currently i dont have skype man,im sorry.i gonna install it but it'll take some time.

Comment: and if you wanna know something i can tell you about codeigniter..in order to solve my issue

Comment: first install skype and send me skype id we will resolve by skype.

Answer (score 0):

You did not load the form helper. If you load models, helpers, etc in a class constructor they are available for every method in your Class. Even easier is going to application/config/autoload.php and putting them there. But here is an example constructor and a bunch of different things that can happen including loading your helpers...

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{

function __construct() {

        // this is always required 
        parent::__construct();

       // load some helpers 
       $this->load->helper('html');
       $this->load->helper('url');
       $this->load->helper('form');

       // load some libraries 
       $this->load->library('form_validation');
       $this->load->library('database');
       $this->load->library('session'); 

      // load models 
      $this->load->model( 'superusers' ); 
      $this->load->model( 'dailyword' );    

      // create a variable with $this that can be used anywhere
      $this->devmessage = '' ; 

      // call a method and return something that can be used anywhere
     $this->wordoftheday = $this->dailyword->returnword() ; 

    }
```

so now any method in the Login class, and any Model or View file called by the Login class will have all the above helpers, libraries, models, etc available. Also spelling the helper names upper case might work on some systems but i would suggest always naming them lower case.